# How to identify and separate standalone applications from libraries in Linux package lists?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, manjaro

I want to generate a list of trending Arch/AUR packages that focuses on user-facing applications rather than background libraries and dependencies.

I wrote a [script](https://git.disroot.org/hirrolot19/trending-linux-packages) that uses the data from [pkgstats](https://pkgstats.archlinux.de) to show non-dependency packages sorted by popularity. However, it doesn't distinguish between applications and libraries, so the output isn't very useful.

I want to identify and separate standalone applications from libraries and dependencies for both Arch official repositories and AUR packages. Not just for installed packages but for all of them.

[pamac](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/applications/pamac), Graphical Package Manager for Manjaro Linux with Alpm, AUR, Appstream, Flatpak and Snap support, seems to identify applications vs libraries/dependencies when grouping packages into categories like "Music & Audio" or "Games". As seen in [this code](https://gitlab.manjaro.org/applications/pamac/-/blob/b6d4815b051d4048f00fa05a57959a5681a031b5/src/manager_window.vala#L3317-3357), pamac gets categorized package lists and populates the UI accordingly.

Since it may not be clear what libraries or dependencies are and I'm already using pamac as an example. I'll consider packages that appear in pamac's categories like Games and Music & Audio as applications, and other packages as libraries/dependencies.

As an alternative, I would consider end-user software the ones that aren't required by any other packages. This isn't perfect, just good enough. For example, [this](https://pastebin.com/hcC4Ax3R) is how I would do this for installed packages.

How can I identify standalone applications and separate them from libraries/dependencies in the Arch/AUR package lists? The end goal is a trending packages list focused on end-user software rather than background components.

Comment: Note: your question is not about Linux, but about a specific distribution. In any case: What do you mean with "libraries"? The problem: some programs uses libraries (as files) internally as "plug-in" formats. Some libraries may include one or few small utility programs (no need to create new package). or how to handle developer/support packages of libraries (to be able to compile programs that uses such library?) It is a complex topic. Check package name convention (and content of package) as first approximation

Comment: I tagged it arch-linux should I change the title? Arch Linux packages are Linux packages so I don't know why the distinction would be needed, it's explained in the body anyways. With libraries I refer to the packages not used by the average end-user but by other packages. For more specificity you can consider libraries all packages that don't appear listed in the category groups on pamac since that's what I'm using as a reference to try to figure out how to accomplish this.

Comment: Sinc eyou also talk about just dependencies, take something like QEMU. It is undoubtedly a "real software", but it's also the dependency of other software like GNOME Boxes. How should it be classified?

Comment: see the previous comment, it should answer this

Comment: Pamac seems to be a Manjaro Linux thing, it's not in the Arch Linux standard repos. What are the "category groups" of pamac? Are they [the package groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Meta_package_and_package_group) installable by `pacman`?

Comment: Just a bunch of software grouped by categories (photo & video, music & audio, productivity, communication & news, education & science, games, utilities, development)

Comment: Here's the packaging source code for VLC in Arch Linux: https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/packaging/packages/vlc and the final package info: https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/vlc/ Neither of them mention a category AFAICT. It seems to be a purely Manjaro thing. Maybe they have a manually curated list, or using some other existing list as a source.

Comment: As an alternative, I would consider end-user software the ones that aren't required by any other packages.

Comment: What is "end-user software"?